# Slow query while using DISTINCT in MYSQL with various other conditions (10 million records)

Tags: mysql, optimization, amazon-rds

I am working on a social Network where, as usual there is a feed for users where they are able to see the activities of users a user is following and not the users who are blocked by the users.

This is the query that is being used currently from the Activities table

```
SELECT DISTINCT `activities`.`post_id` 
FROM `activities` 
WHERE (activities.user_id IN ([followed_user_ids]) AND 
activities.language_id IN ([language_ids]) AND 
activities.id <= ?) AND 
(`activities`.`post_user_id` NOT IN 
([blocked_and_deactivated_user_ids])) 
ORDER BY `activities`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

This is the query which is causing issues. Sometimes the Mysql CPU usage goes to 100% which causes issues to the users. I have also used index on the columns being used in the activity table.

There are 10 million records in the Activities table.

What changes can i possibly do to optimise this?

**Note** - followed_user_ids/blocked_and_deactivated_user_ids - can have an array of thousands of ids.

**Update 1**

This is the new query that i formed ignoring the blocked users from post_user_id :-

```
"SELECT  DISTINCT `activities`.`id` FROM `activities`
INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `activities`.`user_id` AND 
`users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN `follows` ON `follows`.`followable_id` = `users`.`id` 
AND `follows`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `follows`.`followable_type` = 
'User' WHERE `activities`.`language_id` IN (19, 21) AND (activities.id 
< 99999999) AND `follows`.`blocked` = 0 AND `follows`.`follower_id` = 1 
AND `follows`.`follower_type` = 'User' AND `follows`.`followable_type` 
= 'User' AND `users`.`deactivated` = 0  
ORDER BY activities.id desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10"
```

This doesn't seem to help either. I need to get all the unique post activities from the users i am following, in a pagination format.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` ( long list ) often performs badly. Try rewriting using [NOT] EXISTS or [LEFT] JOIN. Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT activities.post_id 
FROM activities 
JOIN <table with followed_user_ids>
   ON activities.user_id = ...    
JOIN user_languages
   ON activities.user_id = ...
LEFT JOIN <table with blocked users> bu
   ON activities.user_id = ...
WHERE bu.<attribute> IS NULL -- no match
ORDER BY activities.id DESC 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 10;
```

Make sure you have appropriate indexes on JOIN predicates.

Comment: The `IN`'s poor performance perhaps being compounded by the `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 10`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your problem is three fold.

1. As has already been mentioned IN with a large list of possibilities has really poor performance.
2. The `ORDER BY` if not done on an indexed column is very very slow. Add the  `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 10` and you're compounding the problem
3. `LEFT JOIN` is very likely to cause you to generate a very, very large list of tuples.

It would be helpful to see the DDL for the table. Also if this is a query that's only being fired every once in a while then you may want to simply cache the result for use later.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` in this question is necessarily slow since no index can handle the `WHERE` with just `=`.  So, the `ORDER BY` will be sorting whatever is left over from the `WHERE`.  The `LIMIT&OFFSET` don't make it any slower, they simply rub salt into the wound by delivering a mere 1 row after all that effort.

Comment: The query is for the feed to users, which is very much dynamic and updated feed needs to be provided to the users.

Answer (score 0):

That seems rather strange in two ways:

- Order by `id`, but do `DISTINCT post_id`
- Exclude newer ids.

Meanwhile, as it stands, there is little that can be done to optimize it.  It needs to

1. Scan most of the table (or at least most of an index)
2. Use the rest of the `WHERE` to toss some rows
3. Dedup based on `post_id`
4. Sort by `id`
5. Deliver the 11th item.

Indexes that *may* help *some*:

```
(id)  -- unless it is already the PRIMARY KEY
(language_id, user_id)
```

Comment: I am trying to fetch all the activities with uniq post_ids so that user only see one instance of each post, and order by id is to show the latest and excluding newer ids for pagination, so that the pagination is maintained by removing the newer activities.

Comment: @AkshayChhikara -- seems like the second page may have a dup `post_id` in spite of what you do with `id`.

Comment: The query that i am currently using checks for activities with distinct post_id thus maintaining the non dup post_id. The result comes out to be correct but the optimisation seems to be an issue.